# 'Parfor' doesn't make code faster in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am having difficulty in using `parfor` in Matlab.

According to the document https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/parfor.html, by using `parfor`, the code should be faster than before.

I exactly follow the example on the website.

```
clear all;
tic
n = 200;
A = 500;
a = zeros(1,n);
for i = 1:n
    a(i) = max(abs(eig(rand(A))));
end
toc

tic
n = 200;
A = 500;
a = zeros(1,n);
parfor i = 1:n
    a(i) = max(abs(eig(rand(A))));
end
toc
```

The results from the document is as follows

> Elapsed time is 31.935373 seconds.
> Elapsed time is 10.760068 seconds.

Clearly, parfor should make the code faster.

But if I run the same code in my Matlab

> Elapsed time is 28.455776 seconds.
> Elapsed time is 27.998243 seconds.

So I don't see any change in elapsed time.

Is there a prerequisite in order to use `parfor` in Matlab?

Comment: Do you have Parallel Computing Toolbox? The documentation you show if part of that toolbox's documentation. `parfor` behaves like a normal `for` if you don't have the toolbox.

Comment: No I don't have it... so that was the reason. Thanks!

Comment: I downloaded Parallel Computing Toolbox and I got the message "Connected to the parallel pool (number of workers: 4)" But still I don't see any change in elapsed time... Am I still missing something?

Comment: Hmm, that's surprising I get `Elapsed time is 26.848743 seconds.` and `Elapsed time is 7.507984 seconds.`.